# Выбрать из таблицы несколько записей по номерам

Tags: sqlite

Не особо шарю в БД, хотя вопрос как мне кажется простой:

Допустим, есть таблица SQLite такого вида:

**id    text**

**1     бла бла бла**

**2     бла бла бла**

**3     бла бла бла**

**4     бла бла бла**

**5     бла бла бла**

К примеру мне нужно выбрать из нее записи с номером 1,2,4.
Как я могу сделать это в один запрос?

Пробовал нечто вроде:

**SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE id=(1,2,4)**

но не получается

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Здесь нужно использовать ключевое слово **IN**, т.е. значение находится в множестве.

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE id IN (1,2,4);
```

Comment: спасибо, работает на ура

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE id=1 OR id=2 OR id=4
```